# Multiple List Comprehensions in One Line - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is more of a curiosity/ efficiency question. I am replacing all numbers in a string with x+1, and if its a 9 changing to a 0. My broken code:

```
def add_one(string):
   return ''.join([(str(int(x)+1) for x in string if x in "012345678") and (y for y in string if y != '9') and (0 for z in string if z == '9')])
```

The goal is that "123abc99" would result in "234abc00".

The code is doable over multiple lines, but is multiple list comprehensions in one line possible?

Comment: `string` is a bad name for a variable in Python because there is a [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). In Python, `and` means logical AND (e.g., `True and False` is `False`).

Answer (score 1):

```
return "".join(str((int(x)+1) % 10) if x.isdigit() else x for x in string)
```

Comment: Nice touch with the `% 10`

Comment: Actually, it was an after-thought.  It wasn't in my original answer, but fortunately his example made it all too clear that without `% 10` it wouldn't work.